# Parameter types using ATL

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, atl

I am trying to create an unmanaged COM dll using ATL that mirrors a C# dll I previously created.  However, when I was adding methods to the interface I came across a problem and have not been able to find a solution.  To illustrate I will include the interface written in C#:

```
public unsafe interface IUserIDA
{
    [DispId(1)]
    void SwitchCriteria(ref double intensity, ref double minMass, ref double maxMass, ref bool selectIntensity, ref long numOfDepCycles);

    [DispId(2)]
    void ChargeStateParam(ref short minCharge, ref short maxCharge, ref bool doChargeState);

    [DispId(3)]
    void InclusionList(ref double intensity, ref double theList, ref short numOfItems);

    [DispId(4)]
    void ExclusionList(ref long exRTWindow, ref double theMassList, ref long theRTList, ref short numOfItems);

    [DispId(5)]
    void OtherCriteria(ref long smartFilterTime, ref double isoExclusionWin, ref double massTolerance, ref bool isPPM);

    [DispId(6)]
    void IsotopeMatchParam(ref double theMassList, ref double theAbundanceList, ref short numOfItems, ref  double abTolerance, ref double maTolerance);

    [DispId(7)]
    void InitIDA();

    [DispId(8)]
    void SurveySpec();

    [DispId(9)]
    void NextScan(double* selectedMasses, double* SelectedIntensities, long* selectedCharges, int itemCount);
```

}

When I tried to reproduce this in my ATL project (using visual studio 2008) I found that a number of the data types were not listed: boolean and integer types.  What type should be used?

Comment: Or I am missing something, or it is as trivial as that: boolean in c# is bool in c++ and integer in c# is int in c++. Is it really what you are asking for?

Comment: @Flot2011 When I try the add method option there is a menu for picking the parameter types, but I do not see bool* or int* on it.  There is variant_bool but think that is defined differently.

Comment: I have not used Visual Studio very much, and this is the first time I have used COM and ATL.  It is certainly possible I can simply use int or bool but I do not know and was concerned due to the omission on the list of possible types.

Answer (score 0):

boolean in c# is indeed bool in C++, and you could go that way. However, in standard COM interfaces you should use BOOL or LONG.
Ditto for integers. Use LONG.
@Travis gave you a good advise. In Visual Studio, open the 'Class View' window (from 'View' menu), right click on your interface, and select Add, and then 'Add Method' or 'Add Property'. That will open a nice UI which will guide you through the definition of the COM interface.

Comment: Thanks @Uni.  That is actually how I had been adding the methods to the interface.  I simply could not find any literature that would indicated whether they were not on the parameter type list for a reason, or what the best practices were.